# Using Import Wizard with Access - No null values

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, import

I am trying to import a table from Access to SSMS using the Import Wizard but when I do the resulting table has a lot of empty strings instead of the NULL values that I am expecting.

How do I make sure that any null values in Access come through correctly as NULL values in SSMS?

Comment: If it's not too many columns you could just update the destination table and set all the blanks to NULL.

Comment: It's quite a few columns. I know I can do a ISNULL(col,'') line for every single column but it seems strange when the blanks are obvious.

Comment: Do any of the columns you expect to come through as NULL come through as NULL? What collation is the SQL DB using?

Comment: The columns I expect to come through as NULL come through with empty strings instead. I'm not too sure what you mean by collation in reference to SQL DB.